# Securing base cabinets to wall across a 3.5"-4" gap

Tags: cabinets

**Facts**
*Task*
I am extending a run of base cabinets in my kitchen into an area into an area that has some pipes mounted externally to the wall. (There was previously a bench there.)

*Gap*
I ordered short cabinets so that they could fit in front of the pipes without modification. After accounting for everything (e.g. the wall isn't parallel to the run!) there is a variable gap of ~3.5"-4" to the wall at the top of the cabinets.

*Wall material*
The walls are some sort of block (most of the apartment is [gypsum block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gypsum_block), but one of the adjacent walls is exterior and so is probably heartier). Yes, my super OK'ed this.

*Current plan*
Attach a rail of 2 2x4s + .5" (ish) hobby board / plywood to space out from the wall and provide something to attach the cabinets to. (Just below the level line, so that it's not going to support the countertop.) Use whatever anchors the local hardware stores recommend for the 2x4 directly on the wall. Shim all four corners of the cabinets so the rail is not bearing any real load (just... its own weight). Attach the cabinets to each other.

*Questions*

1. Is there an easier / less heavy way to attach the cabinets to the wall? Why not just use something that spans the gap - similar to a turnbuckle - given that the lateral movement is constrained by the rest of the run? (Which is flush to the wall)
2. Any anchor suggestions for this? Doesn't seem like the wall screws are doing very much in this situation?

*Edit - Picture & Schematic:*
One snag is that the cabinet on the bottom in the schematic is tall, and so I don't love the idea of it bearing too much horizontal force.
[image: Schematic]
[image: Example]

Comment: Base cabinets don't really need that much securing to a wall, unless used as a hockey goal net or earthquake zone.  You might want some filler material to close the top to wall/hide the gap.

Comment: A drawing of what your plan is would be helpful. However, I'd agree with @crip659 that you probably don't need to go to extremes to attach the cabinets to the walls. If the cabinets can get a screw or two from cabinet back to the wall on either side of the gap, and the carcasses themselves are screwed to each other, you'll probably be fine.

Comment: Thanks both - I added a schematic and a photo of just the corner. The corner situation makes it a bit more complicated I think, but not going crazy on the attachment front feels good to me.

Comment: 1.5"+1.5"+0.5" = 3.5". Why not just install a horizontal 2×4 oriented flat in a couple spots?

Comment: My concern with attaching a flat 2x4 would just be the screw length or angle (if I do it from the bottom). But not a huge issue really...

Comment: The countertops will also give you some stability against the cabinets wobbling.